# SBT system property not being set

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to do `sbt flywayMigrate -Denvi=foo` but the system property `envi` is not being set. Pointers for debugging is greatly appreciated as I haven't been successful in identifying the cause of this issue for hours now. No question in SO or anywhere else have had this issue so far.

In **build.sbt**, this will be used as a variable.

```
lazy val envi = sys.props.getOrElse("envi", "default")
```

Using `sys.env.get("ENVI")` instead is currently not an option due to shared/team repo considerations.

```
sbt console -Denvi=foo
scala> sys.props.get("envi")
res0: Option[String] = None
scala> sys.props.getOrElse("envi", "default")
res1: Option[String] = default
```

`scala`, `sbt` installed using `brew`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the environment variable before the command:

```
sbt -Denvi=foo console
```

otherwise it will be passed as an argument to the main class instead of to the JVM.

Alternatively you can set the environment in the `JAVA_OPTS` variable before starting `sbt`:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Denvi=foo"
sbt console
scala> sys.props.getOrElse("envi", "default")
res0: String = foo
```

Comment: Do you know any possible cause as to why the property doesn't get set along with `sbt`?

Comment: It works if you place the environment variable before the command. I updated my answer.

Comment: You can get debug information from sbt by invoking it with `-d`. Compare the output for `sbt -d console -Denvi=foo` and `sbt -d -Denvi=foo console`